# Unable to find a specification for `Firebase` (adding Firebase SDK by using CocoaPods)

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I tried to add Firebase SDK to my iOS app through CocoaPods.

I followed https://cocoapods.org/pods/Firebase and `$pod install`
gave me this error:

> Unable to find a specification for `Firebase`

I followed some other pages people's suggestions like:

```
pod update Firebase --verbose
```

Or changing pod `'Firebase'` to pod `'Firebase', '>= 2.3.2'` in Podfile.

None of them worked. At the end I gave up and followed Manual Alternative https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/alternate-setup.html.

I appreciate for help to resolve CocoaPods Method.

Comment: Have you recently updated to CocoaPods 1.0? Can you go to `~/.cocoapods/repos/master` and `git pull`? If it fails, you should just blow it away and re-clone it, since it's likely that this is CocoaPods being unable to get the specs from GitHub, rather than a problem with Firebase.

Comment: it seems like google was working on transition from old Firebase SDK to the new one and it was matter of time so "pod install" command works perfectly now

Comment: The issue is that CocoaPods gets into a state where specs can't be updated (the git repo they use gets into a broken state), not anything that Firebase controls, nor is it a matter of time to get fixed--it will remain broken unless you directly fix it (by doing the above), or by performing some CocoaPods voodoo magic which fixes it along the way.

Answer (score 6):

As Mike McDonald said, I had to reset the repo to get it to work.  Something I did had deleted all of the modules.  I could see that the state was funny by running `git status` in `~/.cocoapods/repos/master`.

This worked for me:

```
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
git fetch
git reset --hard
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 
    pod 'Firebase/core'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.